# Linking of static library with demo app through Xcode workspace

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have created static library named  "abc.framework" and also demo app named "DemoApp"with this static library. Now I want to enhance the abc.framework at the same time I want those changes in DemoApp also since it includes framework. For this purpose I have created one workspace and added both above project into it. Now since DemoApp linked to old abc.framework file, I want to change that linking. I done following things,

```
    Demo app project:

•   set USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS to $(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/include $(DSTROOT)/usr/local/include;

    the static library project:
•   add some header files to target's Build Phases > Copy Headers > Public;
•   set SKIP_INSTALL to YES.
```

Still its not working. Anyone has tried this? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about what not working means?

Comment: Not working means...Compilation was successful, but when I was doing changes in framework source code, It was not reflecting in demo app which was linking to old library

Comment: thats just an error code, not a stack track or meaningful at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do that kind of linking by three ways...

1) As mentioned above using "Users Header Search Path". This will link directly to new header files that will build. (Previously It was not working for me as I mentioned above. May be I was not properly clean the build.)

2) We can add .a file from Build Phase => Link binary with Libraries . In this it will show you available .a files in your workplace.

3) We can refer directly framework from derived data path where actual product get created by default. So that once user done changes in framework code in workspace and build it, Demo app can refer directly to new build.